# display checked input field in cakephp 3

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0, cakephp-3.3

I have to display the checked box as I am getting the value in `$selected` variable. Currently in the below scenario i have to show two checkboxes as checked, but my code is not working. How can i fix?

```
$checkboxarray = [
    '0' => "By Value",
    '1' => "By Quantity",
    '2' => "By Date"
];
$selected = explode(",", "0,1");
echo $this->Form->select('mo_type', $checkboxarray, array( 'selected' => $selected, 'multiple' => 'checkbox'));
```

Comment: the key is not 'selected' but it is 'value'

Answer (score 0):

You can try the **default** instead of **selected** attribute,

```
$checkboxarray = [
    '0' => "By Value",
    '1' => "By Quantity",
    '2' => "By Date"
];
$selected = explode(",", "0,1");
echo $this->Form->select('mo_type', $checkboxarray, array( 'default' => $selected, 'multiple' => 'checkbox'));
```

And the proper method is to use "**val**" attribute

```
echo $this->Form->select('mo_type', $checkboxarray, array( 'val' => $selected, 'multiple' => 'checkbox'));
```

Comment: actually seems that the right way to set default values for multiple select is 'val', see [here](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/form.html#creating-select-pickers)